# Updating fact tables in SQL doesn't work properly

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, star-schema

I've been working with SQL Server for 4 months now, and most of my work is on building a Datawarehouse for my company. We normally employ the star schema method, but since there are too many dimensions, I'd normally run UPDATE queries to fill in the dimension columns later. Upon retesting my queries, I've run into a bizarre mistake that I absolutely cannot explain and is making me very afraid.
My data had a `Registered_on` column typed as DateTime. I created a dimension called HOUR with 24 rows, one for each hour of the day and an int for matching. So, the first row is midnight and has a column with a 0.

When I ran the query of

```
SELECT HourDimension.Hour
    ,DATEPART(Hour, AdmissionLogs.Registered_on)
FROM FactTable
INNER JOIN AdmissionLogs ON AdmissionLogs.ID = FactTable.LogID
INNER JOIN HourDimension ON HourDimension.HourNumber = DATEPART(Hour, AdmissionLogs.Registered_on)
```

Everything matched perfectly, as per this image.

[image]

So I did the update query as:

```
UPDATE FactTable
SET FactTable.IdfHourDimension = HourDimension.IdfHourDimension
FROM FactTable
INNER JOIN AdmissionLogs ON AdmissionLogs.ID = FactTable.LogID
INNER JOIN HourDimension ON HourDimension.HourNumber = DATEPART(Hour, AdmissionLogs.Registered_on)
```

And upon reviewing the results of the fact table via:

```
SELECT HourDimension.Hour
    ,HourDimension.HourNumber
    ,DatePart(Hour, AdmissionLogs.Registered_on)
FROM FactTable
INNER JOIN HourDimension ON HourDimension.IdfHourDimension = FactTable.IdfHourDimension
INNER JOIN AdmissionLogs ON AdmissionLogs.ID = FactTable.LogID
```

I got this:

[image]

The hours ABSOLUTELY don't match! I don't know what is going on, but I'm seriously doubting everything I know.

Comment: Sample data and expected results will be more helpful edit and add this to your question.

Comment: Just did so. It's clear to me that datepart works on extracting the data, and so it should be getting the proper records from the Hour Dimension, as it does on the first query.

Comment: The FactTable and AdmissionLogs tables … are a 1-to-1 correspondence?  Otherwise, the hour and the IdfHourDimension will never match, because there are multiple REGISTERED_ON dates that the IdfHourDimension could correlate to.

Comment: They are 1-1. The relationship between the dimension and the fact is one to many.

Comment: So the count of entries in the FactTable and AdmissionLogs tables are the same?  Okay.  What would happen if you added a REGISTERED_ON column in the FactTable, and updated it as well.  In theory it should match, but I'm wondering if it would give you a different value.

Answer (score 1):

```
The results are different because you are not asking the same SELECT.

In the original query in which "Everything Matches Perfectly" you have ...
INNER JOIN HourDimension
 ON HourDimension.HourNumber = DATEPART(Hour, AdmissionLogs.Registered_on)

In the later query, after the UPDATE you have ...
INNER JOIN HourDimension
 ON HourDimension.IdfHourDimension = FactTable.IdfHourDimension


It should read...
SELECT HourDimension.Hour
    ,HourDimension.HourNumber
    ,DatePart(Hour, AdmissionLogs.Registered_on)
FROM FactTable
INNER JOIN AdmissionLogs
 ON AdmissionLogs.ID = FactTable.LogID
INNER JOIN HourDimension
 ON HourDimension.HourNumber = FactTable.IdfHourDimension
```

Comment: I don't follow. Why should I join the fact table to the dimension using an int, rather than the foreign key? This is a problem also due to the fact that the hour number goes from 0-23 while the Idf is from 1-24, resulting in a mismatch.

Comment: If you provide the syntax to create a small sample of the original data I can walk you through it.  It sometimes helps to do a side-by-side comparison of the values that are going to change before you COMMIT an update statement.  In your case I suspect you lost track of how the FactTable.IdfHourDimension value changed.